# List Azure files and folders from File share snapshots with php

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, fileshare, storage-file-share

To list the files and folders from Azure Files can be done with this code:

```
function ListFolder($shareName, $path)
{
    global $fileRestProxy;
    $vMaxResultados = 5000;
    $vNextMarker = "";
    $listResult = null;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            $options = new ListDirectoriesAndFilesOptions();
            $options->setMaxResults($vMaxResultados);
            $options->setMarker($vNextMarker);
            $listResult = $fileRestProxy->ListDirectoriesAndFiles($shareName,$path,$options);
            $vNextMarker = $listResult->getNextMarker();
        } while ($vNextMarker != "");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        return "ERROR:$code:$error_message";
    }
    return $listResult;
}
```

But how is the sintaxis or method to the same with a snapshot from these Share?

This doesn't work:

```
function ListSnapshotFolder($shareName, $path, $snapshot)
{
    global $fileRestProxy;
    $vMaxResultados = 5000;
    $vNextMarker = "";
    $listResult = null;
    try
    {
        do
        {
            $options = new ListDirectoriesAndFilesOptions();
            $options->setMaxResults($vMaxResultados);
            $options->setMarker($vNextMarker);
            $shareFull = $shareName . "?snapshot=" . $snapshot; 
            $listResult = $fileRestProxy->ListDirectoriesAndFiles($shareFull,$path,$options);
            $vNextMarker = $listResult->getNextMarker();
        } while ($vNextMarker != "");
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        return "ERROR:$code:$error_message";
    }
    return $listResult;
}
```

Is there any parameter in the $option object to add?
Or maybe the $shareFull must be created in some format?
$shareFull = $shareName . "?snapshot=" . $snapshot;

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have found a bug in the SDK. I looked up the source code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/5dc75923f11042bca5b3cb6a16c82f3d104002cd/azure-storage-file/src/File/FileRestProxy.php#L1103) and there's no provision to provide `sharesnapshot` query string parameter in the options as well as the code does not even handle it.

```
    public function listDirectoriesAndFilesAsync(
        $share,
        $path = '',
        ListDirectoriesAndFilesOptions $options = null
    ) {
        Validate::notNull($share, 'share');
        Validate::canCastAsString($share, 'share');
        Validate::canCastAsString($path, 'path');

        $method      = Resources::HTTP_GET;
        $headers     = array();
        $postParams  = array();
        $queryParams = array();
        $path        = $this->createPath($share, $path);

        if (is_null($options)) {
            $options = new ListDirectoriesAndFilesOptions();
        }

        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_REST_TYPE,
            'directory'
        );
        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_COMP,
            'list'
        );
        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_PREFIX_LOWERCASE,
            $options->getPrefix()
        );
        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_MARKER_LOWERCASE,
            $options->getNextMarker()
        );
        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_MAX_RESULTS_LOWERCASE,
            $options->getMaxResults()
        );

        $this->addOptionalQueryParam(
            $queryParams,
            Resources::QP_TIMEOUT,
            $options->getTimeout()
        );

        $dataSerializer = $this->dataSerializer;

        return $this->sendAsync(
            $method,
            $headers,
            $queryParams,
            $postParams,
            $path,
            Resources::STATUS_OK,
            Resources::EMPTY_STRING,
            $options
        )->then(function ($response) use ($dataSerializer) {
            $parsed = $dataSerializer->unserialize($response->getBody());
            return ListDirectoriesAndFilesResult::create(
                $parsed,
                Utilities::getLocationFromHeaders($response->getHeaders())
            );
        }, null);
    }
```

You may want to open up an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/issues and bring this to SDK team's attention.

Comment: Ok, I'll open a issue. I let this question open meanwhile. Thanks